# Rails: Query multiple associated tables using Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables with the model below:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The Post table has the following attributes: `views` and `upvotes`.

I want to find the number of `users` with 50 or more `upvotes` in a `post` for each `project`

I have tried doing the following:

```
project = Project.find (1)

users = project.users.joins(:posts).where("posts.upvotes >= ?", 50).count
```

But it's not working.

This is the output I get:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "posts"
> LINE 1: ...rs"."id" WHERE "users"."project_id" = $1 AND (posts...

Any form of help will be appreciated.

Comment: *"But it's working."* - I assume you mean it's **not** working. What is the output of `users`, and how does it compare to your expected output?

Comment: Oh sorry. Yeah, I meant it's not working. Let me correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research and trials, I figured a solution out.

**Solution 1**

```
project = Project.find (1)

project.users.all.map { |project| project.posts.where("upvotes > ?", 50).pluck(:user_id).uniq.count }.sum
```

OR

```
project = Project.find (1)

upvotes = project.users.all.map do |project|
  project.posts.where("upvotes > ?", 50).pluck(:user_id).uniq.count
end

upvotes.sum
```

This looks fine at the first sight. But the problem lies within the total number of queries executed, since each iteration that the **map** function does will execute a query, thus, introducing **N + 1 queries problem**

However, Active Record lets you eager load any number of associations with a single Model.find call by using an array, hash, or a nested hash of array/hash with the `includes` method. So we can eager load the `users` model association, since it's closely associated with the `projects` model. So we will run:

```
project = Project.includes(:users).find (1)
```

instead of

```
project = Project.find (1)
```

This loads the project whose `id` equals `1` and the associated `users`, after which you can iterate over it using **map** function. Although, the queries on `posts` table will still be executed multiple times for every iteration of the **map** function, since it's not eager-loaded.

**Solution 2**

We can also simplify things by adding the `projects_id` to the `posts` table. That way our query will then look like this:

```
project = Project.includes(:users, :posts).find (1)

project.posts.where("upvotes > ? AND project.id IN (?)", 50, project.id).pluck(:user_id).uniq.count.sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
Project.joins(users: :posts)
.where("projects.id = ?", project.id)
.group("projects.id, users.id").having("SUM('posts.upvotes') >= 50")
.length
```

Comment: Thanks. I am having an error. `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "projects.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Can you also use a variable for this, just like how I have it in the question : `project = Project.find (1)` and then `users = ........` instead of passing `projects.id` inside the query.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by doing a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  projects.*,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(users.*) 
    FROM users 
    GROUP BY users.id, posts.id
    INNER JOINS posts ON posts.user_id = users.id
    WHERE users.project_id = projects.id
    HAVING posts.upvotes >= ?
  ) user_count
FROM projects
```

Translated in ActiveRecord/Arel it reads like this:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  def self.with_user_count(min_votes: 50)
    users = User.arel_table
    subquery = User.joins(:posts).group(:id, 'posts.id')
                   .select(users[Arel.star].count)
                   .where(users[:project_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
                   .having(Post.arel_table[:votes].gteq(50))
                   .arel
                   .as("user_count")
    self.select(
      arel_table[Arel.star], # projects,*
      subquery
    )

  end
end
```

It will give you a `users_count` attribute on each Project instance. This column can also be used for stuff like ordering:

```
most_popular = Project.with_user_counts.order(user_count: :desc)
```

Comment: This is really just the the simplest solution and there are a lot of other ways to solve this like CTE's, lateral joins or view tables which can be examined if performance becomes a problem.

Comment: Thanks @max. Is it possible to translate this to ActiveRecord alone and not mixing it with Arel, while I try to test it out in my project.

Comment: No I don't think so. The ActiveRecord query interface can only really express relatively simple queries. Arel is the corner stone of AR anyways so it's not like it's an extra dependency.

Comment: Okay. I just ran the command now, but I'm getting the error  `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 7:     INNER JOINS posts ON posts.user_id`